# Unable to start Windows apps (application of unknown origin)

Tags: windows-8.1, modern-ui, windows-store-app

Opening any app on Windows 8.1 Enterprise will give me the following error:

> This app can't open
>
> There's a problem with [App]. Contact your system administrator about repairing or reinstalling it.

In the `Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational` event log there's a corresponding log message:

> Activation of the app [App] for the Windows.Launch contract was blocked with error 0x80073CFC because its package is in state: Error from application of unknown origin.

So what's an `application of unknown origin` and how can I overcome this problem? Am I missing some certificate here? All of those apps were installed using the Windows Store, so nothing special here ...

**Update:** Message in the system event log

> Unable to start a DCOM Server: Microsoft.WindowsLive.Mail.wwa as Unavailable/Unavailable. The error:
> "15612"
> Happened while starting this command:
> "C:\Windows\system32\wwahost.exe" -ServerName:Microsoft.WindowsLive.Mail.wwa

Comment: Anything in the System Event logs?

Comment: Doesn't tell me too much, however. Back in the old days, you got exceptions with at least some error detail. Nowadays, you just get HRESULTS and useless error codes :(

Comment: [Settings (and other Apps) Will Not Start (Metro)](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-system/settings-and-other-apps-will-not-start-metro/6b79e224-2617-4db3-b64e-928a6022aa11) with the same error suggests a System Restore will fix it.

Comment: the error means ERROR_NEEDS_REMEDIATION: "The application cannot be started. Try reinstalling the application to fix the problem". remove the apps and reinstall them via Store.